# Unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have 1 View Controller and 1 Tab Bar Controller with 2 Navegation Controller.

In my simple View I have one form and then when I click in button "Login" I want to load the first View in my Tab Bar Controller.

With this code works perfect:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    Inicial *telaInicial = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
    [self presentViewController:telaInicial animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I want to send and value to this View "Inicial" and I put this:

```
telaInicial.email = email.text;
```

But I got this error message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setEmail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9fdc8f0'

[image]

Comment: The view controller with identifier "tabBar" is a UITabBarController, not an Inicial.

Comment: this code loads the view that I want with Tab Bar...but I can't send a value...I want to load the same View that I want, with Tab Bar and with the value that I want to send....Yes the "tabBar" is my "Storyboard ID" in my UITabBarController

Comment: Did my answer help? Remember to accept it if it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `telaInicial` that you think is an instance of `Inicial` is actually a `UITabBarController` therefore you cannot set the `email` property on it as it doesn't exist.

I think you want something like this...

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];

UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];

Inicial *telaInicial = navController.topViewController;

telaInicial.email = // blah
```

Comment: with this code I get this error: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Inicial *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController'

Comment: It's a warning not an error. Just cast the result like this... `(Inicial *)navController.topViewController;`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there isn't a setEmail method for the telaInicial object.  Is that an instance of a subclass you've written?  If so, you might be getting the error because you haven't written a setEmail method for it or because you haven't declared the instance variable email as an @property, in which case the setter and getter methods for it would be synthesized automatically by XCode (prior to XCode 4.something, I think you need to synthesize your properties explicitly - after that version, they're automatic).

Comment: In my "Inicial" class I have NSString *email; and @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;...how I use this setEmail?

Comment: Look at the error message - ` '-[UITabBarController setEmail:]`, he doesn't have an Inicial, he has a tab bar.

Comment: I'm having a problem to link to UITabBarController, because if I link to Inicial Navegation Controller I can set the value that I want...but the Tab Bar don't exist

Answer (score 0):

Try to write class, that will store your data.
You can access to it from AppDelegate (not really good solution, but very fast).